# Unable To Read Text File Because Its Open By Another Process VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am having problems trying to read a text file which is open by another process.
After searching SO I have found a few similar questions albeit in C# and nor VB.Net which seem to refer to the fact that FileShare.ReadWrite is the key to getting this to work but yet I am still struggling with it.

This is what I have so far but nothing is appearing in TextBox1.

```
 Dim logFileStream As FileStream = New FileStream("C:\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    Dim logFileReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(logFileStream)

    While Not logFileReader.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = logFileReader.ReadLine()
        TextBox1.Text = line
    End While

    logFileReader.Close()
    logFileStream.Close()
```

My goal is to just use the last 2 lines of what's in the file c:\test.txt and display those contents into a Label but I guess I first need to read and show the content before I can start to look at just extracting the last 2 lines.

Comment: How big is your file? There is a File.ReadAllLines that should be good enough if the file is not big

Comment: The file is around 300 - 400k

Comment: But do you know the process that keeps the file locked? If that process doesn't open the file in a sharing mode that allows you to read it then I don't suppose that you have any chance to read it. It is not something that your code may be able overcome in some way

Comment: I dont know If that process doesn't open the file in a sharing mode but I can open the file at the same time in NotePad when the file is in use

Answer (score 0):

Update:

After re-visiting the MS Docs, I have rearranged the code as below and I can now seem to read the open file into a TextBox

```
 Dim strLogFilePath As String
    Dim LogFileStream As FileStream
    Dim LogFileReader As StreamReader
    Dim strRowText As String
    strLogFilePath = "C:\DSD\DSDPlus.srt"
    LogFileStream = New FileStream(strLogFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    LogFileReader = New StreamReader(LogFileStream)
    strRowText = LogFileReader.ReadToEnd()
    TextBox1.Text = strRowText
    LogFileReader.Close()
    LogFileStream.Close()
```

Comment: You need to call `LogFileReader.Dispose()` and `LogFileStream.Dispose()` after the closes. The [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement will take care of that for you (even if an exception is raised).